# Creating instance of an object with String[] as one of the parameters

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering how to create an instance of an object that takes a String[] type as a parameter.  So far it comes up with an error saying that I cannot initialise an array when creating a new instance.  This is my code:

```
public class Profile{

    public Profile(String[] interests) {

        this.interests = interests;

    }
}

public class ProfileTest{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Where the error appears
        Profile newProfile = new Profile({"Interest1","Interest2","Interest3"});

    }
}
```

I don't want to use an arraylist or anything - just String[].

Comment: this.interests is not a field of your class Profile. You should add a private/public/protected field interests in your class

Comment: Profile newProfile = new Profile(new String[] {"Interest1","Interest2","Interest3"});

Answer (score 0):

To fix the compilation error, use a variable to hold the string array like this:

```
String[] array = {"Interest1","Interest2","Interest3"};

Profile newProfile = new Profile(array);
```